# Confusion regarding branch cut

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I have confusion regarding branch cut. In some problems they take postive x axis, in some negative axis(in case of $z^a$) and in some cases like log, they take negative y-axis as branch cut. How do we decide branch cut line? can you pls explain me?

Comment: You choose the cut that is going to make it easy to identify the poles inside the contour, but more particularly leave you with a contour that is easy to work with.

Comment: Branch cut are, kind of, arbitrary. You choose the one most suited for your problem

Comment: I am 43 years old and have had a PhD in mathematics since I was 29.  I still do not understand branch cuts.  Fake it 'til you make it...

Comment: Tq all ..... got it